# List View Population Errors

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have 3 columns that need populating when a user presses 'search' however every time that I click 'search' only the Employee ID appears, neither the 'First Name' nor the 'Last Name' are present in the List View. The data does exist in my Access Database, this is proved as the program produces a blank record instead of a null value error. The code that I am using to populate the List View is:

```
        ds.Clear()
        lstClockin.Items.Clear()
        con.ConnectionString = provider & datafile
        con.Open()                                          'Open connection to the database
        sqlstatement = "SELECT * FROM [EmployeeAccounts]"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstatement, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "allmembers")                           'Fill the data adapter
        con.Close()
        Dim recordCount, x As Short
        recordCount = 0
        x = 0
        recordCount = ds.Tables("allmembers").Rows.Count
        With ds.Tables("allmembers")
            Do Until x = recordCount
                lstClockin.Items.Add(.Rows(x).Item(0))
                lstClockin.Items(x).SubItems.Add(.Rows(x).Item(1))
                lstClockin.Items(x).SubItems.Add(.Rows(x).Item(2))
                lstClockin.Items(x).SubItems.Add(.Rows(x).Item(3))
                x = x + 1
            Loop
        End With
```

The first 3 columns in the Database are, [Employee ID], [First Name] & [Last Name]

Any suggestions are welcome; however I have ruled out using a DataGridView or any control. As this program needs to use a ListView. Thankyou in advance!

Comment: Why not using TreeView

Comment: It's not the same layout nor, what I need for this specific program _"this program needs to use a ListView"_

Comment: ok @Matt E have a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that can be improved in the code:

```
Dim SQL = "SELECT Id, Name, Fish FROM Sample"

Using dbcon As New OleDbConnection(ACEConnStr)
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, dbcon)

        dbcon.Open()
        Dim lvi As ListViewItem
        myLV.SuspendLayout()
        Using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            Do While rdr.Read

                lvi = New ListViewItem(rdr.GetInt32(0).ToString)
                If rdr.IsDBNull(1) Then
                    lvi.SubItems.Add("")
                Else
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(rdr.GetString(1))
                End If

                If rdr.IsDBNull(2) Then
                    lvi.SubItems.Add("")
                Else
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(rdr.GetString(2))
                End If
                myLV.Items.Add(lvi)
            Loop
        End Using
        myLV.ResumeLayout()

    End Using
End Using
```

- Connections and other DB Provider objects allocate resources which need to be released or your app will leak.  `Using` blocks for things that implement `Dispose` will close and dispose of them for you
- There is no need for an `DataAdapter`, `DataSet` and `DataTable` since you are copying the data to the control.  This code uses a `DataReader` to get the data.
- Rather than `SELECT *` the query specifies the columns/order so it can use the `Getxxxxx` methods to get typed data.  That doesnt matter a great deal *in this case* because everything gets converted to string for the `ListView`.  `lvi.SubItems.Add(rdr(COLUMN_NAME).ToString())` would also work.
- It seems unlikely the ID column could be null, so the code only checks the other 2 for `DbNull` (another thing the DGV can handle without help).
- Since the `ListView` is suboptimal and slow in adding items, `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` are used to minimize paints while it is populated.

[image]

I am not at all sure what `...the program produces a blank record` means, but in order use a `ListView` like it is a grid, the `View` property must be `Details` and you have to have added 3 columns in the IDE (or manually create them in code).  Nothing will show without those settings.

If the `DataTable` is needed/used elsewhere, you can still fill one without a `DataAdpater` and populate the LV from it:

```
...
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

    lvi = New ListViewItem(row(0).ToString())
    If DBNull.Value.Equals(row(1)) Then
        lvi.SubItems.Add("")
    Else
        lvi.SubItems.Add(row(1).ToString())
    End If
    If DBNull.Value.Equals(row(2)) Then
        lvi.SubItems.Add("")
    Else
        lvi.SubItems.Add(row(2).ToString())
    End If
    myLV.Items.Add(lvi)
Next
```

This uses a different DBNull check since it is using a `DataRow` and not the `DataReader`.